# "error C2248: 'sf::NonCopyable::NonCopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'sf::NonCopyable'"

Tags: c++, sfml

I realise this may be a duplicate, but I have searched through many forums and questions and know what causes the problem, but can't spot it in here. I am using SFML 2.0, and I have traced the error to:

```
void GameObjectManager::DrawAll(sf::RenderWindow& wnd){
    std::map<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>::const_iterator itr;
    for(itr = gameObjects.begin();itr!=gameObjects.end();itr++){
        itr->second->draw(wnd);
        itr++;
    }
}
```

I think this is something is not copyable, but I can't see what it is here.

Comment: While not related to the error you describe, the code is incrementing the iterator twice. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: `++itr` might work better than `itr++`. Do you really mean to have two increments in that loop?

Comment: The full error message should ususally show what tries to invoke what, or what tries to invoke the copy ctor.

Comment: Can you post the signature for `VisibleGameObject.draw()`?

Comment: Oops, that second increment shouldn't be there. I'll post the signature for VisibleGameObject.draw(), see upcoming edit

Comment: If you have solved your problem then post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted instead of editing the question :)

Comment: Can it be you're trying to copy a non-copyable object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RenderWindow](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php) inherits from `sfNonCopyable`.

`VisibleGamObject.draw()` is probably attempting to copy `wnd`.